# Load comments from open graph object into Facebook comments social plugin

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, facebook-comments

I have created a website connected my facebook app. Users can login and post a custom action connected to a custom object with open graph, javascript sdk. This will also post with 'fb:explicitly_shared' set to true so it will generate a post on the users timeline. So these custom objects have their own url and on those pages i want to have the comment plugin. And i want that object page (with the comments plugin) and the post on the users timeline to share comments.

I have tried setting a lot of different things in the "href"-property on the comments plugin but nothing seems to work. However i have managed to get the comments of the timeline post with a call to '/objectid/comments' with FB.api(). I can use that to build my own comments ui, but i rather use the comments social plugin. Is there any way to make it happen?

Comment: I think I just posted essentially the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14593651/is-it-possible-to-use-facebooks-comments-plugin-with-graph-object-ids-graph-urls it IS possible to build your own, but I have not successfully found out how to it with FBs own plugins. Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

The Post ID and the Open Graph Object ID are different, so I do not believe that they can share comments. Comments are based off a single Facebook ID. Also, it is not currently possible to write comments to an Open Graph Object from the API (comments plugin only) so you can't really create your own comments plugin for an OG object.